# How can i record voice on my app and then send it to server?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, voice

Im trying to build an application that will record voices (mic) on my iPhone,
and then will send them to store on my server.

can anyone help me with this one.
i even don't know where to began with this :)

Thank you very much,
Oded.

Comment: Nobody is going to write the code for you. Try writing some code to record your voice. If it doesn't work, come back here, show us what you tried and why it didn't work. You'll find people will be much more receptive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just google it "how to record iphone" and you get it in a seconds.
2. After recording, file will create in your Documents folder.
3. Retrieve that path and extract data in NSData and send to server through POST method.

Sample code,

```
NSLog(@"SendingRecordedData");
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your_server/fileupload.php"];
    NSLog(@"Url:%@",urlString);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];    
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pics\"; filename=\"record.caf\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];



[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data2]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:&err];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: sendSynchronousRequest is bad as it blocks the thread so DO NOT DO IT IN THE MIAN THREAD (especially for large chunks of data like audio), or prefferably use asynchronous APIs.

Answer (score 0):

there is sample code with recording - [SpeakHere](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802) on iOS developer site. After recording you can save it and send as any binary file.